# Can't add item to the end of Linked list

Tags: c

This code adds only one element to the end of list(just creates head element, nothing after that).What is wrong in my program? Should I pass two items in function, head and item or just one?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MyList
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct MyList * next;
}List;

typedef List * Item;

void AddEnd(Item * head);
void PrintList(Item * head);

int main(void)
{
    int response;
    Item head;
    head = NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1- Print, 2 - Add to End, 3 - exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &response);
        switch(response)
        {
            case 1: PrintList(&head); break;
            case 2: AddEnd(&head); break;
            case 3: return 0;
        }       
    }    
    return 0;
}

void PrintList(Item * head)
{
    Item temp;
    temp = *head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", temp->x, temp->y);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void AddEnd(Item * head)
{
    Item new, temp;
    new = (Item)malloc(sizeof(new));
    printf("Enter x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &new->x, &new->y);
    new->next = NULL;
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = new;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = *head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp = new;
    }

}
```

This code down that I just tried don't work also:

```
void AddEnd(Item * head, Item * item)
{
    Item new, temp;
    new = (Item)malloc(sizeof(new));
    printf("Enter x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &new->x, &new->y);
    new->next = NULL;
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = new;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = *head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp = new;
        *item = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program will crash because you're creating objects with size of a pointer `(List *)`. Change it to `List` instead of `Item`

Comment: @UchiaItachi Ooh, good catch; didn't see that one the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AddEnd` function in the `else` clause, when you exit the while loop, `temp` is now `NULL`. However, the element before it is still pointing to `NULL`.

Try something like

```
temp = *head;
if (temp->next == NULL) {
    temp->next = new;
} else {
    while((temp->next) != null) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new;
}
```

in your `else` clause.

<del>(This, and the apparent issue with your understanding of malloc referenced by the others, `new` should be a `Item *` and the malloc call should be `malloc(sizeof(Item))`. You also don't need to cast the return value of malloc (indeed, there are some pitfalls that happen if you do).)</del> Reading your typedefs a little more closely, `new` *should* actually be an `Item` (since it's a pointer to a `List` struct and you have `typedef List* Item`). Try `new = malloc(sizeof(List));` and just declare `new` to be of type `List *`. (The `typedef List * Item` makes your code hard to read; it becomes less clear what's a pointer and what isn't.)

Comment: my program now crashes after adding third element , two work fine

Comment: I reread your typedefs a little closer; read my edit. One of the problems that I realize that has been going on is that you're allocating room for a *pointer*, and not allocating room for a *struct*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
new = (Item)malloc(sizeof(new));
```

To this:

```
new = (Item *)malloc(sizeof(List));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Even if Item is a List *?  I'd think he'd want Item new; new = malloc(sizeof(List));

Comment: @Eric it would be <type> *<name>; <name> = (<type> *)malloc(sizeof(<type>));

Comment: Sorry to be so confused... but in his code he has a typedef List * Item;    So the type Item already is a pointer, and List is the name of the actual class type.  Or am I missing something horribly obvious?